# How can i generate sinusoidal wave in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

How can i generate sinusoidal wave in Matlab with frequency of 1 HZ and sampling frequency 200 HZ and sequence length N=1024 ?

```
N=1024;
fs=200;
f=1;
ts=1/fs;
t=-10:ts:10;
i=1:2:N;
x=sin(2*pi*f*i*t);
```

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2):

The code below will create a 1024 sample sine wave that has a frequency of 1Hz and sampling rate of 200 Hz.

```
N=1024;
fs=200;
f=1;
ts=1/fs;
t = ts*(0:N-1);
x=sin(2*pi*f*t);
plot(t,x)
```

This should plot what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
f1 = 1 ;
N = 1024 ;
fs = 200 ;
ts = 1/fs ;
t = -(N/(2*fs)):ts:(N/(2*fs) ;
y = sin(2*pi*f1*t) ;
plot(t,y)
```

You do not need to use i for getting 1024 samples out. this can be done by choosing correct start and stop values for t.

Comment: Thank u all for elaboration

Answer (score 1):

```
fs=200;
f=1;
N=1024;
ts=1/fs;
t = ts*(0:N-1);
x=sin(2*pi*f*t);
```